# FortiClientVPN 7.0.1.0083 - Opening after silent installation asking admin credentials

Tags: silent-install, forticlient

I've to uninstall FortiClient 6.07 and install FortiClientVPN 7.01.0083 at a stretch. Just after silent uninstallation with noreebot, I've installed the VPN client as norestart. However, when opening the VPN client, its asking for elevated credentials to open. But if rebooted after installation, it won't ask. How can I resolve this? Thanks

Uninstall FortiClient 6.07

```
MsiExec.exe /x {FE1638FD-CCFF-4C7E-9064-AA2B68C9094C} REBOOT=ReallySuppress /qn
```

Install FortiClientVPN 7.01

```
FortiClientVPN.msi /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: Use a tool such as Process Explorer to see what the program is actually doing to better understand why this behavior is occurring and resolve it.